# How logical to create social app with Solana blockchain?

Tags: solana-program, fees, dapp

I keep seeing questions about Twitter, TikTok, Facebook Solana-related apps questions on different forums.

Since the request-response cycle should be as minimum as possible in social apps, it makes sense to use the Solana blockchain which is considered to be the fastest blockchain as of now.

But for each transaction to be executed on any smart contract, the client has to pay a fee. In social app examples, for each comment, for each like etc. So why the hell people would use social media apps deployed on the blockchain if it will cost them for each like or comment?